NSBatchInsertRequest: Handling one-to-many relationship
In my app, an AudioFile has a one to many relationship with UpNextItem. I realised that NSBatchInsertRequest can't handle relationships at all which is a huge drawback.
How do I handle associating each up next item to their respective audio file without high cpu usage and blocking the main thread especially since I am expecting there to be over 10k to 100k up next items?
Task {
                                let upNextItemsContext = DataController.shared.createNewBackgroundContext()
                                
                                var objects: [[String: Any]] = []
                                
//Delete old up next items on disk

                                await upNextItemsContext.perform {
                                    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: UpNextItem.fetchRequest())
                                    if let batchDeleteResult = try? upNextItemsContext.execute(deleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult, let success = batchDeleteResult.result as? Bool, success {
                                        return
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                await upNextItemsContext.perform {
                                    var index = 0
                                    audioFiles.forEach {
                                        defer {
                                            index += 1
                                        }
                                        
                                        let properties: [String: Any] = [
                                            "name": $0.wrappedName,
                                            "artist": $0.wrappedArtist,
                                            "fileExtension": $0.wrappedFileExtension,
                                            "index": index,
                                            "id": UUID()
                                        ]
                                        
                                        objects.append(properties)
                                    }
                                    
                                    let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: UpNextItem.entity(), objects: objects)
                                    insertRequest.resultType = .objectIDs
                                    
                                    do {
                                        let result = try upNextItemsContext.execute(insertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult
                                        let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
                                        let changes = [NSInsertedObjectsKey : objectIDArray]
                                        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes as [AnyHashable : Any], into: [moc])
                                    } catch {
                                        fatalError("Failed to perform batch update: \(error)")
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                //Do a second pass over each up next item to associate with the correct audio file. But this is causing like 200% CPU usage and hangs my app for over 2-3 seconds
                                let upNextItems = try? moc.fetch(UpNextItem.fetchRequest())
                                let fetchRequest = AudioFile.fetchRequest()
                                upNextItems?.forEach { upNextItem in
                                    let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", upNextItem.wrappedName)
                                    let fileExtensionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "fileExtension = %@", upNextItem.wrappedFileExtension)
                                    
                                    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [namePredicate, fileExtensionPredicate])
                                    let audioFile = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
                                    upNextItem.audioFile = audioFile?.first
                                }
                                
                                try? moc.save() //Save the changes
}


let audioFile = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest); upNextItem.audioFile = audioFile?.first You could start by setting a fetchLimit to 1, it might save a little. You could also save the objectIDArray, as I guess else it might get upNextItems that have already been set, and fetch only the UpNextItem that need to be set? Depending on your AudioFile entities, you might also want to limit what you retrieve per AudioFile (like includesSubentities = false, or something like that).
